# SVG ID name appear on mouseover

Tags: javascript, svg

I created several svg shapes in the form of a map.

What I want to happen is, that when you hover over the corresponding shape, the title/name of the shape is displayed below.

So if I would hover over the rect representing mile end road, Mile end road should appear as underneath the SVG shapes.

How can I do this?

I've tried adding this:

```
<script>
    var elem = document.getElementById("qmul-map");
    elem.innerHTML = myMile;
</script>
```

But it doesn't seem to be doing anything.

Comment: Any reason to tag question with jQuery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use a `<title>` element...

```
<rect id="mile_end_road" height="34" width="623" y="377" x="10" stroke-linecap="null" stroke-linejoin="null" stroke-dasharray="null" stroke-width="5" stroke="#000000" fill="none">
    <title>Mile end road</title>
</rect>
```

and so on for the other elements